# DAX equivalent of Excel PERCENTRANK.INC per category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to calculate in DAX equivalent of Excel function PERCENTRANK.INC but per Category. I admit that I do not know even how to calculate it for Category. Any hints will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Here is M code for sample data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcisqzSwpVtJRSiwoyEkF0oZKsTpIwkmJeUAIZJigipfn56QlpRYVVQLZpqhSyRlQcWOweFhqempJYlJOKlgusagovwTIMMKUK8gvSSzJhzsBRS4/LzM/D0ibo1qFw9HILogFAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, Product = _t, Amount = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Amount", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure below would produce the desired result. As there is no PERCENTRANK function in DAX, you can manually calculate it from the results of RANKX and COUNTROWS.

```
Percent Rank Within Category = 
IF (
    -- This calculation only makes sense if there is only one product
    -- in the current filter context. If there are more than one products
    -- or no product in the filters, BLANK should be returned.
    HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[product] ),

    -- Get all products which belong to the same parent category with
    -- the product currently being filtered
    VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE (

        -- all products, in the modified filter context of...
        VALUES ( MyTable[product] ),

        -- no filter on product
        REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[product] ),

        -- and under the same parent category
        VALUES ( MyTable[Category] )
    )

    RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        -- PERCENTRANK = (<rank of product> - 1)
        --               / (<total N of products> - 1)
        DIVIDE (

            -- Sales rank of each product in ascending order
            RANKX (
                tbl,
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( MyTable[Amount] ) ), ,
                ASC
            ) - 1,

            -- Total number of products
            COUNTROWS ( tbl ) - 1,

            -- When there is only one product, it should return 1
            1
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, it works even better then expected. It shall be a pleasure to accept this answer. Could you please comment lines of your code with explanation what each line does? What is the purpose of Subcategories variable? What is it supposed to return? Is the combination of VALUES and REMOVEFILTERS similar in results with ALL function? What is the purpose of has one value?

Comment: Added line by line explanation. Does it make sense?

Comment: Kosuke, I would like to calculate Category based on the value of [Sales]. Probably I should do it with Summarizecolumns then, instead of Calculatetable?

Comment: Do you mean dynamic segmentation? In that case, Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957928/how-can-i-do-a-customer-segmentation-for-month-and-see-the-customer-number-filte). If it doesn't help you to solve the problem, please ask in another question.

Comment: No, I mean something else. Suppose that the defined by you variable Subcategories had the following shape: `var Subcategories = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( MyTable[Subcategory] , "NewCategory", IF( [Sales] > 4, "high", "low" ) )`Say, the category was not defined in Column of a table, but calculated from sales value per plant. Then I would like to have Rank for each of these high and low categories.

Comment: I recommend to post another question with more details. There are 3 ways to do that in my mind, but I’m not sure which one to suggest because it depends on the details of use case. And the space is too small to answer here.

Comment: Here in this question lurks bounty for you. Please take time to review related questions posted in the comments. Here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59191631/1903793

Comment: Your function produces wrong results (blank) for Category contains only one product. It's because division by zero happens. Excel equivalent function returns 1 in that case. Can you please see to it?

Comment: I was not thinking of that edge case, but it is easy to address that case. We can specify the alternative value which DIVIDE should return if the denominator is BLANK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write it. Very similar to Kosuke's answer but maybe more readable.

```
Percent Rank =
VAR ProductsInCategory =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( MyTable[Product] ), ALLSELECTED ( MyTable[Product] ) )
VAR RankProduct =
    RANKX ( ProductsInCategory, [Sales],, ASC )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( MyTable[Product] ),
        DIVIDE ( RankProduct - 1, COUNTROWS ( ProductsInCategory ) - 1 )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Your solution produces different from Kosuke's results. It is obvious, if there is a slicer on Product. This is a meaningless difference. Replacing ALLSELECTED with ALL deceptively mimics Kosuke's solution. If we remove Category from table visual, Kosuke's still produces expected results, that is percentage rank within category buckets, while your solution then treats all products as a single category.

Comment: I would have assumed that if you didn't have category broken out in the visual, then you wouldn't want to separate categories but use whichever formulation fits your use case.