# DAX REMOVEFILTERS vs ALL

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to substitute [REMOVEFILTERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax) in the following code with old school functions ALL and VALUES instead? This exercise is just to better understand REMOVEFILTERS.

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    -- get all products, in the modified filter context of...
    VALUES ( MyTable[product] ),
    -- no filter on product
    REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[product] ),
    -- and under the same parent category
    VALUES ( MyTable[Category] )
)
```

As far as I can read the hints [here](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/removefilters-in-dax/) that could be possible.

Here goes sample data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcisqzSwpVtJRSiwoyEkF0oZKsTpIwkmJeUAIZJigipfn56QlpRYVVQLZpqhSyRlQcWOweFhqempJYlJOKlgusagovwTIMMKUK8gvSSzJhzsBRS4/LzM/D0ibo1qFw9HILogFAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, Product = _t, Amount = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Amount", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

REMOVEFILTERS is just an alias of ALL here, so it works just the same.

Basically, ALL returns a table including all rows, ignoring any filters that might have been applied.

However, when ALL is used as a filter argument of CALCULATE or CALCULATETABLE, it behave totally differently: it removes filters from the table and does not return a table.

To alleviate this confusing behavior of ALL, REMOVEFILTERS was introduced to replace ALL when it is used inside CALCULATE.

For more details, you may look at this article.
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the code in the question with the function ALL? If so, how?

Comment: Simply replace REMOVEFILTERS with ALL, Nothing more, nothing less. Think of it as a same function having two different names.

Comment: In that case of replacement, do we have to keep the line `VALUES ( MyTable[product] ),` before `REMOVEFILTERS ( MyTable[product] ),`. Isn't it that ALL has both virtues of extracting all distinct values and keeping them unfiltered?

Comment: I guess I slowly get out of the trap of single name for dual functions. `FILTER(ALL` gets the table, whereas `CALCULATETABLE(..., ALL(` is just a mere filter remover and does not bring table as result. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct. The first ALL inside FILTER returns a table. The second ALL inside CALCULATETABLE does not, it is actually working as REMOVEFILTERS.