# average divided by the count per project

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three tables time, SectorProject, product Project.

```
Time AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,48),(201,520),(36,120))V(id_project,time)),
SectorProject AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,'BM'),(1011,'Fi'),(1011,'Om'),(201,'BM'),(36,'BM'))V(id_project,Sector1)),
    prductProject AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,'bike'),(1011,'velo'),(1011,'pc'),(201,'n'),(36, 'r' ))V(id_project,product))
```

I need to calculate average divided by the count per project

[image]

With sql server it will something like the following code:

```
avg( sum(time)) over (partition by t.id_project) * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by t.id_project)
```

How to do the same thing within Dax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for "sum by category" to find the correct DAX pattern.

```
SumOverPartition:=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( T[Sales] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'T' ),
    VALUES ( T[Category] )
)

CountOverPartition:=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( T ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'T' ),
    VALUES ( T[Category] )
)
```

You could also achieve it with ALLEXCEPT function but the pair REMOVEFILTERS and VALUE is better. Learnt the hard way.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-allexcept-versus-all-and-values/
In that article, they use the archaic name ALL instead of [REMOVEFILTERS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191836/1903793).

If you want it in calculated column, then you have to wrap it with another CALCULATE.

```
SumOverPartition:=
CALCUALTE
   CALCULATE (
       SUM ( T[Sales] ),
       REMOVEFILTERS ( 'T' ),
       VALUES ( T[Category] )
   )
)
```