# Power BI DAX: ALLSELECTED with exception of one column

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-analysis-services

#### Context

Because of some business requirements I found myself with a `DAX Measure` calculated on a `Fact` and using an `ALLSELECTED` over the entire `Dimension`. The dimension contains the following fields `'Dimension'[Field 1]`, `'Dimension'[Field 2]`, `'Dimension'[Field 3]`, `'Dimension'[Field 4]`.

```
[My Measure] := CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Quantity]), ALLSELECTED('Dimension'))
```

#### Question

Now, for some other specific business requirements, I need `ALLSELECTED` to work on all fields of `'Dimension'` except for `'Dimension'[Field 4]`.

My current implementation becomes as follow:

```
[My Measure] := CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Quantity]), ALLSELECTED('Dimension'[Field 1], 'Dimension'[Field 2], 'Dimension'[Field 3]))
```

This does the job but is not a long-term solution. Is there a more elegant and robust way to state the same `DAX` query, something like `ALLSELECTED('Dimension, EXCEPT('Dimension'[Field 4]))`

Comment: Perhaps try using `ALLEXCEPT`?

Comment: @JustynaMK do you base this comment on knowledge or is it just a hint? because as far as I know from what I understood, ALLEXCEPT is not the complement of ALLSELECTED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[My Measure] :=
CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Quantity]), ALLSELECTED('Dimension'), VALUES('Dimension'[Field 4]))
```

`VALUES('Dimension'[Field 4])` will be evaluated in the original filter context, and thus contains filtered values of `'Dimension'[Field 4]`. This can be used to apply the filter again which has been removed by `ALLSELECTED`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I need two more details before marking this as the answer: (1) Are you aware of any possible side-effect or risk in using this solution? (2) how should I modify your DAX formula in the case I would like also 'Dimension'[Field 3] to not be changed by ALLSELECTED?

Comment: Regarding (2), you can simply add `VALUES(Dimension[Field 3])` to the filter parameter of `CALCULATE`. I frequently use this pattern and never aware of a situation this might result a wrong answer... However, as ALLSELECTED has really complicated nature, it is hard to say there is nothing I'm overlooking. This article may help. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/

Comment: may I ask why do you use this pattern? In this case, it is a very specific measure to answer a 14 pages requirements document. In general, I never used this pattern but maybe it is something could be extended to other (more general) scenarios.

Comment: Combination of ALLSELECTED and VALUES might not be very common... Most typically I use ALL (or REMOVEFILTERS) along with VALUES. An instance of use case is aggregation for parent group in a hierarchy. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102487/dax-equivalent-of-excel-percentrank-inc-per-category/59126284#59126284